# bootstrap 4 datepicker display one side deviation

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I use bootstrap 4 datepicker for my function. everything were ok. But now I check this function again. It is showing issue. all of day col were put in to one header col due to wrong font in datepicker box. What may be cause of this problem? help me..
I changed version of bootstrap but it still not working.

below a photo about this problem:

https://scontent.fhan2-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/48412332_1919886578128398_1344189841545363456_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_ht=scontent.fhan2-3.fna&oh=a072d101da99f15c1e57aaebf5cc115b&oe=5CA190F3

Comment: can you provide working pen or fiddle ?

Comment: show us what you did, and where is your problem

Comment: the problem just occur when I integrate datepicker into my project

Comment: @ÂuThịnh, so show that's part, and how suggested before, in pen or fiddle site